# Priority queue in C++ is out of order after pop()

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I created a priority queue of Events, which is sorted by Event.time. I inserted 5 events and it worked very well (they are sorted in order of Event.time). However, after I pop(), the remaining queue are out of order (not sorted anymore). Can someone help me explain why ? Thanks a lot.

```
struct Event
{
    string name;
    int time;
    int pid;
};

class CompareEvent
{
public:
    bool operator()(Event& event1, Event& event2)
    {
        if (event1.time > event2.time)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};
```

main class

```
priority_queue<Event, vector<Event>, CompareEvent> eventList;

    Event newEvent;
    newEvent.name = eventName;
    newEvent.time = time;
    newEvent.pid = pid;

eventList.push(newEvent);

eventList.pop(); // the remaining items are not in order anymore
```

Updated solution: I debugged the program and I looked at the eventList value in the debug windows. The values are not sorted. However, it always return the lowest value when top(). The values are not sorted internally. Thanks for making me realize this.

Comment: What do you mean by not in order? Did you try to pop everything out and observe that they are not in the correct order? It seems your `eventList` contains no element after `pop()`.

Comment: How do you check the order of the remaining items? Note that a priority queue is usually implemented as a heap, i.e. it is ***not*** sorted internally.

Comment: Just a side note, but you could have spared some lines by declaring `operator()` as a `struct` and defining it as `return event1.time > event2.time`. Of course I would like to add to the question how do you check, items are not in order. A piece of code reproducing the bahaviour would be nice. Even if it's somewhat long, it's nice whenanyone can run it and check for themselves right away.

Comment: I debugged the program and I looked at the eventList value in the debug windows. The values are not sorted. However, it always return the lowest value. Thanks for making me realize this.

Answer (score 2):

Priority queue is not required to be sorted. Only requirement is the *heap property* - if you call `pop()` or `top()`, it has to return the top element (the lowest one given the sorting function).

If you need a container that keeps elements sorted, use `std::set` or `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need sorted events at all time, you have to [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) or use a sorting container like [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). The [priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) only guarantees that [pop()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) returns one of the lowest element (the top) in it.